# IAM to restrict Instance Type

Tags: amazon-iam

I am trying to set up some restriction on the type of instances that people can launch.  I have the following policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:key-pair/CI",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:instance/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:image/ami-*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:subnet/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:security-group/sg-a363xxxx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceType": "m4.4xlarge"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The first part of the statement works fine,  but I am trying to add the Deny piece.

```
{
"DryRun": true, 
"ImageId": "ami-5f709f34", 
"KeyName": "FE-CI",
"SecurityGroupIds": [
    "sg-a363bada"
], 
"UserData": "", 
"InstanceType": "m4.4xlarge", 
"SubnetId": "subnet-xxxxx", 
"EbsOptimized":false}
```

when adding the Condition statement everything gets denied. Here is the decoded authorization message.

```
{
        "DecodedMessage": "   {\"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":true,\"matchedStatements\":{\"items\":[{\"statementId\":\"\",\"effect\":\"DENY\",\"principals\":{\"items\":[]},\"principalGroups\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"xxx\"}]},\"actions\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"}]},\"resources\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"*\"}]},\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"ec2:InstanceType\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"m4.4xlarge\"}]}}]}}]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{\"principal\":{\"id\":\"xxx\",\"name\":\"jellin-test\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/jellin-test\"},\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxx:key-pair/FE-CI\",\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"ec2:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-1\"}]}}]}}}"
}
```

I am not seeing anything obviously wrong here.  My understanding is that the first statement should pass and the second one will only deny if the InstanceType is not m4.4xlarge

Answer (score 0):

The `StringNotEquals` key needs to be changed to `StringNotEqualsIfExists`. There is a good explanation of why this happens [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IfExists).